# Dynamics AX 2012 InventJournalTrans table fields

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics

I have a mod in my environment that enables you to assign a fixed asset to an inventory item and serial  number. Now I'm trying to change the count journal line form to display the same fixed asset id and serial number every time I create a new count journal line.

At the moment, it seems like the InventJournalTrans has miscellaneous fields available to place on the form. Does this assignment appear anywhere outside of the InventJournalTrans table?

Also, what allows assets to be available for the Fixed Asset to Inventory journal?

Comment: I am not sure I get your question. "Does this assignment appear ...", Which assignment?

Comment: Ultimately I'm trying to see what populates the AssetID field within InventJournalTrans Table. Currently there is no Asset ID field on the Count journal lines form. If I add the field the the form, the FA ID will be populated alongside the item I pick. Does this relationship between the asset ID and inventory item appear anywhere else in AX? Also are there any other ways to populate this asset ID field in InventJournalTrans table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Update the cross reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa626961.aspx) to answer the question yourself.

You can search for the use of the `AssetId`, especially search for "write".

To my knowledge there is not a relation between `AssetId` and `ItemId`, and even if there were, then updating the count journal would update inventory, but not the asset subsystem. You may prove me wrong using the cross reference.

Comment: Thank you. This is a very useful tool :)

Correct, it is a mod in my environment.